# Login/Register from a Client to a Server

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, client-server

so I was hoping that there would be someone who could show me/direct me to creating a Login/ Registration server within Java. I am creating a Chat Client for some friends and I, and I would like to have the user to be able to Login/Register an account, sending the information to the server to store in a database for later use. Any ideas?

I have created JFrames, and got my basic things done for the Client so far, I have not yet begun working on the server.

Comment: What seems to be the problem, because you are not asking us to write you (or find) tutorial, right?

Comment: You should probably get a server working before you worry about client authentication.